# Pretzel recipe with a twist

Tags: geometry, enigmatic-puzzle

Browsing the geometry section in the local library you come across a flimsy book, seemingly misplaced:

> "The Pretzel Cookbook: *Five More Patterns Using The Spoke Method*"

What's more, it's been ripped in half. Flicking through the remaining three pages, you ask yourself:

1. How are these pretzels formed?
2. What was on the three missing pages?

---

**Page 1:**

> Page 1 — Contents
>
> Page 2 — The "Five"
>
> Page 3 — The "Minus a Half"
>
> Page 4 — The "One"
>
> Page 5 — The "Two"
>
> Page 6 — The "Minus Five"

**Page 2:**

> [image: Page 2]

**Page 3:**

> [image: Page 3]

---

*Hint*

> The sequence of the pages isn't important

*Hint*

> You could solve this with drawing equipment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the pretzels are formed by drawing plots of

> the trochoids $x=r\phi + A\sin(\phi)$, $y=r + A\cos(\phi)$ with $r=1$, $\phi\in [0,4\pi]$ and $A$ the value of the page title. The word 'spoke' gave the solution away for me, we can get these shapes by sticking a light to a bike's spoke, and following this light.

That means the pretzels on the missing pages are:
Page 4:

> [image: Page 4]

Page 5:

> [image: Page 5]

Page 6:

> [image: Page 6]

Comment: more intuitively, you could say that the page title is the distance (in spokes) that the light is placed above the wheel's axle (before cycling for two wheel rotations)